# How do I take full name of students(including space) as input from console and store it in an array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, list, vector

How do I take full name of students(including whitespace) as input from console and store it in an array in c++? Example arr[0]=John Smith, arr[1]=David Clark?
where John Smith and David Clark is entered from console as input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the regular `cin>>"John Smith";` , which doesnt read spaces, u have to use `getline(cin, John Smith);` Initialize the array with the size you want ( the size of it are the number of inputs) and use a `for()` loop the size of the array to print them (in case you want to print them)

Comment: //My output should look like this:


Enter the no. of students:
2
Enter the name of the students:
John Smith
David Clark
The name of the students are:
John Smith
David Clark


#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int s;
cout<<"Enter the size of array\n";
cin>>s;
string arr[s];
cout<<"Enter the name of the students\n";
for (int i=0;i<s;i++){
    getline(cin, arr[i]);
    }
cout<<"The name of the students are:\n";    
    for (int i=0;i<s;i++){
    cout<<arr[i]<<"\n";
    }
 return 0;
}


But, my code is not taking David Clarke, its only printing John Smith

Answer (score 0):

```
while (getline(std::cin, sBuf))
 vNames.push_back(sBuf);
```

where `sBuf` is `std::string` and `vNames` is `std::vector<std::string>`

This will get you all the names with surnames you want till there is data left.

Comment: Thanks, let me just show you where i am stuck exactly,

Comment: //My output should look like this:


Enter the no. of students:
2
Enter the name of the students:
John Smith
David Clark
The name of the students are:
John Smith
David Clark


#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int s;
cout<<"Enter the size of array\n";
cin>>s;
string arr[s];
cout<<"Enter the name of the students\n";
for (int i=0;i<s;i++){
    cin>>arr[i];
    }
cout<<"The name of the students are:\n";    
    for (int i=0;i<s;i++){
    cout<<arr[i];
    }
 return 0;
}

Comment: Changing your `cin >> arr[i]` to `getline(cin, arr[i])` should fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getline(cin, variableName);`. Where as `cin` is the input stream you need to specify (it could by `cin` which is console standard input - keyboard or file variable), a variableName is the name of an array you want to store it in with appropriate index number.